# How to find the best pixel value representing skin in image in CIE LAB color space?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to represent the best LAB pixel value (it could be mean, median or something else) representing the skin in this image.

Following is the code that I tried for this [input image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6M1w.jpg):

```
image = cv2.imread('face.jpg')
image = image.astype("float32") / 255
imgLab = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
L, a, b = cv2.split(imgLab)
LL=np.zeros((512, 512))
aa=np.zeros((512, 512))
bb=np.zeros((512, 512))
data=[]
width, height, channels = imgLab.shape
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        if (50 <= L[i,j] <= 100):
            LL[i,j] = L[i,j]
            aa[i,j] = a[i,j]
            bb[i,j] = b[i,j]
LL = LL[LL!=0]
aa = aa[aa!=0]
bb = bb[bb!=0]
L_mean = np.mean(LL)
a_mean = np.mean(aa)
b_mean = np.mean(bb)
print(L_mean, a_mean, b_mean)
```

It is clear that the face has dark skin pixels. But when I take the mean here, I'm getting a LAB mean pixel corresponding to light skin color.

Comment: define "best"? if your explanation has anything to do with the human vision, you have to calculate in RGB space, and only then convert to Lab, because, you know, people see RGB, not Lab.

Comment: Search Google. There should be numerous articles about skin color.